# JSliderNews jQuery Plugin circular

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, jslider

Hi I'm using the JSliderNews jQuery Plugin, but I the end of the slideshow it goes back to the first one but showing all previous slides. I want it to be circular without showing all the previous slides.

Here you have an example : http://rtl-this.com/sites/default/files/demos/lofslidernews/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready( function(){ 
                // buttons for next and previous item
                var buttons = { previous:$('#jslidernews1 .button-previous') ,
                                next:$('#jslidernews1 .button-next') };
                 $obj = $('#jslidernews1').lofJSidernews( { interval : 5000,
                                                        easing          : 'easeInOutQuad',
                                                        duration        : 1000,
                                                        auto            : true,
                                                        maxItemDisplay  : 3,
                                                        startItem:0,
                                                        navPosition     : 'horizontal', // horizontal
                                                        navigatorHeight : null,
                                                        navigatorWidth  : null,
                                                        mainWidth:1026,
                                                        buttons:buttons} );     
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`direction:'opacity',`

That should do the trick.

Comment: and `direction:'opacitys'` ?